# Im not sure why im getting multiple outputs in my Rock Paper Scissors python game

Tags: python

Here is my code,

```
import random
import time
import sys


a = "rock"
b = "paper"
c = "scissors"

a < b
c > b
a > c

compg = random.choice([a, b, c])
if compg == a:
    cag = "rock"
if compg == b:
    cag = "paper"
if compg == c:
    cag = "scissors"



answer = input("Would you like to play?: (yes/no) ")
if answer == "yes":
    print("Let's play")
    choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors. SHOOT!: Enter your answer.")
    print("You chose " + choice + " was it right?")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    #done what happens when they are equal
    
    if choice == "rock" or choice == "Rock" and compg == a:
        print("Draw.")
    if choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper" and compg == b:
        print("Draw")
    if choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors" and compg == c:
        print("Draw")
  
    #now determining what happens when they are different

    if choice == "rock" or  choice == "Rock" and compg == b:
        print("You lost the computer picked: Paper ")
    if choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper" and compg == a:
        print("You won and beat the computer it picked: Rock")  
    if choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors" and compg == a:
        print("You lost. The computer picked Rock and you picked: Scissors ")
    if choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors" and compg == b:
        print("You won! The computer picked: Paper")
    if choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper" and compg == c:
        print("You lost the computer picked: scissors ")
    if choice == "rock" or choice == "Rock" and compg == c:
        print("You won. The computer picked: scissors ")
```

I feel like I should be getting one output but I have been getting multiple.

Here is an example:

```
Would you like to play?: (yes/no) yes
Let's play
Rock, Paper, Scissors. SHOOT!: Enter your answer.rock
You chose rock was it right?
Draw.You lost the computer picked: PaperYou won. The computer picked: scissors
```

Comment: Your `IF` statements aren't worded how you actually want them. Put the two choice checks in parens.

Comment: `and` has higher precedence than `or`. `a or b and c` is the same as `a or (b and c)`, not `(a or b) and c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change code to this:

```
import random
import time
import sys

a = "rock"
b = "paper"
c = "scissors"

a < b
c > b
a > c

compg = random.choice([a, b, c])
if compg == a:
    cag = "rock"
if compg == b:
    cag = "paper"
if compg == c:
    cag = "scissors"

answer = input("Would you like to play?: (yes/no) ")
if answer == "yes":
    print("Let's play")
    choice = input("Rock, Paper, Scissors. SHOOT!: Enter your answer.")
    print("You chose " + choice + " was it right?")
    time.sleep(1)
    
    #done what happens when they are equal
    
    if (choice == "rock" or choice == "Rock") and compg == a:
        print("Draw.")
    elif (choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper") and compg == b:
        print("Draw")
    elif (choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors") and compg == c:
        print("Draw")
  
    #now determining what happens when they are different

    if (choice == "rock" or  choice == "Rock") and compg == b:
        print("You lost the computer picked: Paper ")
    elif (choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper") and compg == a:
        print("You won and beat the computer it picked: Rock")  
    elif (choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors") and compg == a:
        print("You lost. The computer picked Rock and you picked: Scissors ")
    elif (choice == "scissors" or choice == "Scissors") and compg == b:
        print("You won! The computer picked: Paper")
    elif (choice == "paper" or choice == "Paper") and compg == c:
        print("You lost the computer picked: scissors ")
    elif (choice == "rock" or choice == "Rock") and compg == c:
        print("You won. The computer picked: scissors ")
```